# div image background clickable position

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

[image: l have this image]

l have this image above

l am trying to find a solution to make this image clickable for reservation position seat.

simple array :

```
seats: any=[
    
    {
      id:1,
      selected:false,
      price:50,
    },
    {
      id:2,
      selected:false,
      price:35,
    },
    {
      id:3,
      selected:false,
      price:35,
    },
    {
      id:4,
      selected:false,
      price:35,
    },
    {
      id:5,
      selected:false,
      price:35,
    },
    {
      id:6,
      selected:false,
      price:35,
    },
    {
      id:7,
      selected:false,
      price:35,
    },
  ]
```

html code :

```
<div class="main_back">
   
</div>
```

css :

```
.main_back{
   background-image: url('../../../assets/seat.jpg');
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

If i use CSS and ngfor i will not get the current position layer for each seat, if the seat is booked or not when hovering on seats like red or green color .
using position `absolute` or `relative` .

any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested you the "seats" was .svg (and remove the seats from the image), so we can to have an array of object with almost this properties: x,y,selected and ocupped

```
  seats=[{x:10,y:10,selected:true,ocupped:true},
         {x:130,y:10,selected:true,ocupped:false},
          ....
        ]
```

A simple .html like

```
<div class="car">
  <svg
    class="seat"
    (click)="!seat.ocupped && seat.selected = !seat.selected"
    [class.ocupped]="seat.ocupped"
    [class.selected]="seat.selected"
    *ngFor="let seat of seats"
    [style.top.px]="seat.y"
    [style.left.px]="seat.x"
  >
    <!--replace with a beauty seat-->
    <rect width="50" height="50" rx="5" ry="5" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

See the property "ocupped" makes "not selectable" the seat

And a .css like

```
.car{
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  ....
}
.seat{
  position:absolute;
  fill:silver;
}
.seat:hover:not(.ocupped) {
  opacity:.5;
  cursor:pointer
}
.seat.selected{
  fill: lightsteelblue;

}
.seat.ocupped{
  fill: #DA4567;
}
```

make the trick. See an ugly [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vikz9u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

NOTE:I don't like the path you use in the background. I'm pretty sure that the background should be

```
background-image: url('assets/seat.jpg');
```

think that in production (and in develop) the .index.html and the .css is in the folder "dist" and the assets are in the folder "dist/assets"

Comment: You saved me, thank you so much. l have a question. If I want to change the position of seats. How i will know the current `x` and `y` positions? there is a tool?

Comment: Use a tool for draw. I imagine also there are extensions of navigators that show the coordinates (I've never use so I can not recommended any in particular). Think that, as you use "position:relative" in the "car class", you need substract the upper-left coordinate of the "car". Also I recomended you clean the seats of the images and create an svg seat (I can not found in the web a seat from top) using programs like [inkscape](https://inkscape.org) to make .svg

Answer (score 0):

if you have a set of car images that are not going to change more often and are definite some how, you can rely on seat positions on each images based Image Map elements to make them interactive. example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

basically you need to get coordinates of seats and then you can add any interaction you need to so with seats/

Comment: l tried that. but l need to use color for each seat if his still booked or not. Image map doesn't support colors

Comment: you can add elements inside of that `map` and add custome styles for that as child of it I think

Comment: I mean using `area` like `<area {...attrs}>INTERACTIVE_HTML_ELEMENT</area>`

Comment: l tried that. its not working